Using races suited for the job but untrained vs Using races bad for the job but trained for it?
basically would you be better off using your engi trained in fighting for boarding and your trained for repair mantis for fixing, or just use your engi and mantis for what he's born to do even if they don't know how. this is asking for the moment and not long term, as the mantis will get fully trained. also would a fully trained human be able to outperform either mantis or engi untrained?

Crew skills will give a 20% bonus to repairing or combat when maxed out. Conversely, Engi repair twice as fast, and deal half as much damage in combat. Mantis are the opposite; 150% damage, 50% repair speed.
I don't know if the 20% bonus is additive or multiplicative, but the answer is the same: it's better to use crew that are naturally suited to the task, regardless of experience. Experience bonuses cannot negate racial penalties.

Beat me to it by 2 minutes. +1 to everything said.
